# Can I make my last ball and then the 8 ball in the same shot in 8 ball pool?

Tags: rules, pool

If I make my last ball, and the cue ball travels around the table and pockets the 8 ball in the same pocket, do I win or lose?

After all I made the 8 ball in my last pocket and you don't have to call your last pocket since it's the only choice you have unless your playing a 3 or more rail.

Comment: What game are you asking about?  8-ball?

Comment: 8 ball last pocket

Answer (score 1):

[WPA Rules](https://wpapool.com/rules-of-play/)

On a shot where you your colored balls are still on the table, you cannot call the eight ball.

> 3.6 Shots Required to Be Called
>
> The eight ball may be called only after the shot on which the shooter’s group has been cleared from the table.

So on the shot you've described, the eight ball could not have been legally called. In that case, sinking the ball is a loss.

> 3.8 Losing the Rack
>
> The shooter loses if he
>
> (a) pockets the eight ball and fouls.;
>
> (b) pockets the eight ball before his group is cleared;
>
> (c) pockets the
>   eight ball in an uncalled pocket; or
>
> (d) drives the eight ball off the
>   table.

Comment: thank you, however why would you have to call the shot on the 8 ball when playing last pocket since there is no choice but to pocket in the same pocket as you made your last ball?

Comment: You'll need to specify which rules you are playing under (I gave a response for WPA rules, but you may be using some others).  There's nothing in WPA rules that suggests the 8 ball must be made in the same pocket.  Without such a rule, it can be shot into any pocket.